# Hiding header in React-Native app with TabBar on top staying visible

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-collapsible

I've been trying to implement a rather common UI pattern. I've got a react-navigation MaterialTopTabNavigator that contains a number of ListViews. When the currently active ListView is scrolled down, the header above the Tabs is supposed to be hidden (by translating it up, out of the viewport), the tabs should as well move up.

[Like in this picture](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/23520539/24209019/61958c5a-0f25-11e7-9e91-34808813bc85.jpg)

The problem I'm facing here is either
a) if i translate the header and the tabs up, i need a paddingTop in the lists to make sure the first item is completely visible. But if i scroll down and the header is hidden and then switch to the next tab (where the list is scrolled to the top) the padding will be visible.

or

b) If i translate the whole thing (header, tabbar, and ListView) the paddingTop is not necessary (I can add a padding at the bottom and hide it via a BottomTabNavigator) but the animation gets jerky on android.
There seems to be a [bug in react-native causing](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21801) this.
But there are apps around for Android that implement this pattern.

I'd be grateful for any ideas or pointers around this.

Comment: https://github.com/PedroBern/react-native-collapsible-tab-view this library has now released v3 and claims to be able to do that. Haven't tested it yet.